# Inheriting both abstract base interface and its implementation gives C2259

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I have the following condition:

An absract base class with **many** pure virtual functions:

```
interface IBase
{
    virtual void foo1() = 0;
    virtual void foo2() = 0;
    virtual void foo3() = 0;
    virtual void foo4() = 0;
    virtual void foo5() = 0;
    //  ...
    virtual void fooN() = 0;
};
```

Two small interfaces that inherit it:
Version-A:

```
interface IBaseExt_A :
    public IBase
{
    virtual void foo_A() = 0;
};
```

Version-B:

```
interface IBaseExt_B :
    public IBase
{
    virtual void foo_B() = 0;
};
```

I create base class that implements all of the `IBase` interface functions:

```
class CBase :
    public IBase
{
public:
    virtual void foo1() { /* Do something... */}
    virtual void foo2() { /* Do something... */}
    virtual void foo3() { /* Do something... */}
    virtual void foo4() { /* Do something... */}
    virtual void foo5() { /* Do something... */}
    //  ...
    virtual void fooN() { /* Do something... */}
};
```

Now, I want to implement both derived versions with **minimal code**.
I was hoping to do something like:

```
class CBaseExt_A :
    public IBaseExt_A,
    public CBase
{
public:
    virtual void foo_A() { /* Do something... */}
};
```

Apparently this gives error:
`C2259: 'CBaseExt_A': cannot instantiate abstract class...`
These errors refer to all `IBase` interface functions.

I know I can solve it the long way by delegating all `IBase` functions to `CBase` implementation:

```
class CBaseExt_A :
    public IBaseExt_A,
    public CBase
{
//  IBase implementation:
public:
    virtual void foo1() { CBase::foo1();}
    virtual void foo2() { CBase::foo2();}
    virtual void foo3() { CBase::foo3();}
    virtual void foo4() { CBase::foo4();}
    virtual void foo5() { CBase::foo5();}
    //  ...
    virtual void fooN() { CBase::fooN();}

//  IBaseExt_A implementation:
public:
    virtual void foo_A() { /* At last - do what we came here for...*}
};
```

But this makes my *small class* `CBaseExt_A` become big and complex.
**Is there a way how to avoid all this manual delegation coding?**

Many thanks, PazO

Comment: virtual inheritance might help.

Comment: Interface keyword in C++? What compiler are you using?

Comment: @KirillKobelev - I added:        #define interface   struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following code:

```
interface IBase
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    ......
};

class CBase : virtual public IBase
{
    void foo() { }
    ......
};

interface IBaseExt_A : virtual public IBase
{
    virtual void foo_A() = 0;
};

struct CBaseExt_A : public IBaseExt_A, public CBase
{
    virtual void foo_A() { /* Do something... */ }
};
```

Note that both places where the `IBase` class is inherited should be marked as virtual.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify one of the two inheritance to be virtual.

That is a diamond inheritance where

IBase is the top level

IBaseExt_A and CBase are the middle level

CBaseExt_A is the bottom level

so in CBaseExt_A you want to specify from which path implement the top level, I would say that you may want to specify CBase inheritance in IBaseExt_A to be public virtual instead of just public.

```
class CBaseExt_A :
public IBaseExt_A,
public virtual CBase
{
public:
    virtual void foo_A() { /* Do something... */}
};
```

Comment: I found that I need to add the 'virtual' keyword in all places where 'IBase' is inherited...